# How to handle AWS EFS mount permissions using Chef?

Tags: chef-infra

Let's say I have an EFS volume mounted on three servers. Within the volume I have some folders that get created by Chef. Since this volume gets mounted across 3 different servers, should I apply the same recipe to all 3 servers? It seems kind of redundant since server1 would "create" the dirs and set the permission, and server2 and server3 would run the same recipes, therefore doing essentially the same thing to the shared volume.

Should I be handling EFS volumes differently with Chef?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say, as long as you have consistent UIDs/GIDs across the servers, do it everywhere. This gives you some nice benefits:

1. In a new environment, you don't have to care which server comes up first.
2. If you ever want to split the storage, you don't have to do extra modification to recipes - everything still works.
3. The dependencies are more explicit. You know that your other resource needs that folder to work. It may be obvious now, but in the future if you're moving to a new environment, it's an explicit link between those resources.

In practice, the recipe needs to be idempotent, so having it shared should not cause any issues. It shouldn't introduce a noticeable slowdown either (after the first time it's just a `stat()` check).

Comment: Gotcha. Yeah the other thing I noticed is that the I was missing the `tomcat` user on the DB server. This app requires the EFS volume to be mounted on the DB server as well. We don't have tomcat installed on it but the files/dirs on the EFS volume are owned by `tomcat.` I ended up creating the `tomcat` user on there, not what I wanted to do but it works.